# Pyserial - Struct Packing

Tags: python, pyserial

I have a struct to pack data to send using pyserial to a microprocessor

This is the command I have currently

```
write_bytes = struct.pack('<' + 'B' * len(input_array),  *input_array)  # '\xff\x10\x11' B stands for unsigned CHAR
ser.write()
```

It is giving my error Type Error: 'int' object is not callable.

Also a same problem when I am doing this

```
data_read = struct.unpack('<' +'B' * len(data_read), data_read)
```

The funny thing is the same line of code is working when I write in a single file. However when I write this piece of code in a different file and call it from my main file. I am getting this problem

Comment: please post full traceback. The error may be somewhere else.

Comment: I've tested your example and can't find anything wrong.

Comment: Something like that could happen if you have declared a variable with name `len`.

Comment: Yes I unfortunately declared a variable with name len and it screwed things up. I corrected it and things are good. Thank you very much every one.